# java.io.IOException: The issuer can not be found in the trusted CA list

Tags: java, http, exception, matlab, https

I'm getting this exception when calling a java function from matlab, the function runs fine in eclipse:

java.io.IOException: The issuer can not be found in the trusted CA list.
The exception occurs at the second line:

```
URLConnection Conn = URL("https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginBoxAuth").openConnection();
Conn.getInputStream();
```

I've matlab 2011a installed.
I've also changed the jvm of matlab to the latest jre6.4 but it's  still giving me this error
I've also tried changing the cacerts file but no success.

Any Ideas? I'll be very gratefull

Comment: What you posted is not valid MATLAB code. How are you calling this from MATLAB?

Comment: This is a different error than the one that comes up for that two-step verification option, correct?

Comment: I've got the solution and I'll post it after 7 hours, stackoverflow is not allowing me to post it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the java's URL class in matlab you would have to pass the handler.
I used this constructor:

```
URL(null, ServiceLoginBoxAuthUri, sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler);
```

and it worked fine.

Note:  sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler is only available in matlab

Answer (score 0):

callSoapService.m in MATLAB behaves differently between R2011b in 32bit (issuer is found) and 64bit (issuer not found). This can be resolved by replacing

url = URL(endpoint);

with

url = URL([], endpoint, sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler)

Thanks for posting this fix!